# SharePoint 2010 ClientObjectModel : Find Item by GUID

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list of 6000 listitem GUIDs.  I need to check if each item still exist on the Web.

Previously, I was using the `SPWeb.GetFile(GUID)` method to check the item.

But now I need to convert that process usinig the **ClientObjectModel**.  I cannot find a way to retrieve the item using the GUID.

I even tried from the "List" object.  And can't find a way to retrieve the item from its GUID neither.

Please help! :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use CAML Query.

Ex CAML Query:

```
<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value type='Counter'>"+fileIDtoFind+"</Value></Eq></Where></Query>
```

For more details see:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ee857094.aspx